# What protocol does a Toshiba Machine Provisor TC200 PLC speak over Ethernet?

Tags: node-red, plc, industrial

What protocol does a Toshiba Provisor TC200 speak?

I have a glass molding machine that has this PLC in it, along with a Toshiba HMI connected via Ethernet.  I snooped the connection between them and it's TCP to port 2000 of the PLC.  I have been searching for documentation on this PLC for hours, and I can't find much.

I have mild hints it may speak modbus/tcp or Ethernet/IP but no real details.  It looks like this PLC is used mainly in Toshiba's own equipment.  The Wireshark captures of the communications don't look like modbus or ethernet/ip.

My goal would be to connect to this device from node-red - it's an Industry 4.0 project, I just want to get some cycle count data from the PLC.  If I need to buy some kind of gateway that'd be fine, but something tells me I could talk to it directly if I could figure out the protocol.

It's POSSIBLE that Toshiba invented a proprietary protocol for this, but maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

The Tc200 is communicating Modbus. I have a diecast machine with the same controls. From what i understand you need the TCEN-1 module, then a cross over cable to another PLC preferably a Mitsubishi Q series. I haven't tried it yet, but I'm going to try to find another way. The Enet is already in there. Can you please let me know if you made any headway on this.

Comment: Will do.  I'm hoping I can reach it by Modbus/TCP but I'm not yet sure - when I get back to the machine I'll try.  I don't know how I'd map registers like XA01 to modbus registers but hoping it'll be obvious - XA01 is read input register addr=0001 ... we'll see!

Answer (score 0):

The Toshiba Provisor TC200 PLC may use a proprietary protocol for communication with its HMI. Without more detailed documentation or information about the specific communication protocol, it's difficult to say for sure.

However, it's also possible that the PLC uses a standard industrial communication protocol such as Modbus or Ethernet/IP. Still, the communication is encapsulated or tunneled in a proprietary way that makes it appear different in packet captures.

It might be worth trying to communicate with the PLC using those protocols to see if you can get any response.